# Obtener un solo registro, en Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT *
FROM ct_factura,ct_dosificacion,ct_contrato_cuenta
WHERE ct_contrato_cuenta.n_id_factura = ct_factura.n_id
and ct_dosificacion.n_id = ct_factura.n_id_dosificacion
and ct_factura.n_id (5456,5470,5458,5459,5460,5461,5462,5463,
5464,5465,5466,5467,5468,5469,5457)
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta, en donde `ct_factura` y `ct_dosificacion` devuelven un solo registro, sin embargo el `join` entre `ct_factura` y `ct_contrato_cuenta`, devuelve mas de una registro, ¿Cómo hago para que solo hagan el `join` y me devuelva un solo registro entre estas dos tablas: `ct_factura` y `ct_contrato_cuenta`? En la imagen se muestra la tabla `ct_contrato_cuenta` :

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: select *       
from ct_factura,ct_dosificacion,ct_contrato_cuenta

Comment: Y si traes solo los datos que necesitas en el select (en lugar de *) y usas un distinct? sigue sin entenderse como queres resolverlo. Si trae mas de un registro es porque hay una relacion 1 a n. como queres resolver dicha relacion? trayendo que cosa?

Comment: Estimados volvi a editar la pregunta, al parecer los confundi, ahora esta correcta la pregunta, gracias de antemano

Comment: Si lo hice de esa forma, pero el detalle es que no debo utilizar distinct porque despues debo utilizar un group by para obtener otros datos, con distinct funciona, pero se raya con el group by

Comment: Puedes usar la clausula `rownum = 1` o puedes hacer un `ct_factura = ( select  bla bla bla where rownum = 1 order by bla ;`